# Binding only part of the margin property of WPF control

Tags: wpf, binding, margin

I have this:

```
<TabControl Margin="0,24,0,0">...</TabControl>
```

I want to bind only the `"Top"` part of the TabControl, which intuitively I would do it this way:

```
<TabControl Margin="0,{Binding ElementName=TheMenu, Path=Height},0,0">
 ...
</TabControl>
```

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Have you tried using a converter like this?

**in VB.Net**

```
Public Class MarginConverter
  Implements IValueConverter

  Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Return New Thickness(0, CDbl(value), 0, 0)
  End Function

  Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return Nothing
  End Function
End Class
```

**Or in C#**

```
public class MarginConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness(0, System.Convert.ToDouble(value), 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MarginConverter x:Key="marginConverter"></local:MarginConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="Slider1"></Slider>
        <TabControl Name="TabControl" Margin="{Binding ElementName=Slider1, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource marginConverter}}">
            <Button>Some content</Button>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:**
*Using a MultiConverter*

It is also possible to get all four values during run-time and use a MultiValueConverter. *The Top-Property of the Thickness-Object is not a Dependency-Object*, therefor you can't define a binding to it (unless your source is not a Dependency-Object).

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MarginConverter x:Key="marginConverter"></local:MarginConverter>
    <local:MultiMarginConverter x:Key="multiMarginConverter"></local:MultiMarginConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="Slider1"></Slider>
        <Slider Name="Slider2"></Slider>
        <Slider Name="Slider3"></Slider>
        <Slider Name="Slider4"></Slider>
        <TabControl Name="TabControl">
            <TabControl.Margin>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiMarginConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="Slider1" Path="Value"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="Slider2" Path="Value"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="Slider3" Path="Value"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="Slider4" Path="Value"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TabControl.Margin>
            <Button>Some content</Button>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**... and c#**

```
  class MultiMarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return new Thickness(System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]),
                           System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]),
                           System.Convert.ToDouble(values[2]),
                           System.Convert.ToDouble(values[3]));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**Edit(2) Reverse-Binding:**
I'm not sure if this will make you happy. In my humble opinion I would try to avoid this, but ok... If your source is a Dependency-Property, you can bind this to the Margin:

```
<Slider Name="Slider5" Minimum="-99" Maximum="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=TabControl, Path=Margin.Top, Mode=OneWayToSource}"></Slider>
```

But I've got some effects with this.
The trick is, that you do not bind a part of the Margin of your TabControl to "something else", but bind "something else" to the Margin of your TabControl and specify Binding-Mode *OneWayToSource*.

Comment: But this way forces me to enter all the other numbers in the code, isn't there a way to use sub-tags in the markup, like: `<TabControl.Margin.Thikness.Top="{Binding...}"...>`

Comment: See Edit for details and suggestion with MultiValueConverter. Top (and Bottom and....) are no Dependency-Properties. For a Binding, at least one part has to be a Dependency-Property.

Comment: I've noticed that when adding a `FallBackValue` to a `Binding`, it gets converted to `Thickness` before it's passed to the `MultiMarginConverter` which causes it to error out. Is there something that can prevent that, or do I have to just pull it apart in the converter?

Answer (score 29):

Actually `Margin` property of a control is of `Thickness` Type. So we can bind it to Property if type Thickness.

```
 public Thickness LeftMargin { get; set; }
```

and You can set a part of a Thickness object too. Like -

```
 LeftMargin = new Thickness(20,0,0,0);
```

and in `Xaml` we can bind this property directly to margin property of any element..like this..

```
 <TextBlock Text="Some Text"  Margin="{Binding LeftMargin}"  />
```

Comment: I think if you have only _one_ side to bind, this is the right approach. Otherwise, if you need different values for each side of the control's margin, other options are needed.

Comment: @heltonbiker I think it is perfectly fine, you can set left, right, top and bottom individually, with different values.

Comment: @CularBytes I guess he meant, if you need to bind each side to different properties. This cannot be done with just one `Margin` attribute. MultiBinding is the only approach then, as far as I know.

Comment: See my answer for a straightforward solution to bind multiple margin properties.

Answer (score 12):

You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632079/how-do-i-modify-only-the-right-or-left-top-bottom-value-of-a-wpf-controls-m/12632081#12632081) answer from another question.

The solution uses an attached property that allows for XAML like the following:

```
<Button ap:MoreProps.MarginRight="10" />
```

The attached property is also backed by a DependencyObject so data binding will work.

Comment: This is the best answer, allowing cumulative independent bindings of margins, and the only one offering this feature in all the related threads I read about it.

Comment: Much better than the top answer, because it's a natural, logical approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have used this workaround for left margin only with StackPanel. Benefit is that you don't need any Converter.

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <TextBlock Name="tbkFulltextCaption"
             Text="Static Caption:"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
              DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
      <FrameworkElement Name="feLeftMargin"
                        Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tbkFulltextCaption, Mode=OneWay}" />
      <TextBlock Text="(some text with margin of tbkFulltextCaption.Width)"
                 Name="tbkUnderNonsense" 
                 FontSize="8"                                       
                 Foreground="Gray">
      </TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
  <TextBox Name="tbFulltextSearch" />
</DockPanel>
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgE2a.png)

Answer (score 4):

From your code, I figure that your menu and tabControl may overlap, so you want to use margin to separate them. I feel this practice like two Column CSS Layout.

Back to the point, I think you can apply `TranslateFransform` to `TabControl.RenderTransform`. You can bind `Y` property.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Ioop's method of making a property to control margin instead of a converter if you aren't attaching to another WPF element:

Create 4 standard properties and a readonly property, like so-

```
Public Class CustomMargin
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _Left As Double
    Private _Right As Double
    Private _Up As Double
    Private _Down As Double

    Public Sub New()
      _Up = 0
      _Down = 0
      _Left = 0
      _Right = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Vertical as Double, Horizontal as Double)
      _Up = Vertical
      _Down = Vertical
      _Left = Horizontal
      _Right = Horizontal
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Left as Double, Up as Double, Right as Double, Down as Double)
      _Up = Up
      _Down = Down
      _Left = Left
      _Right = Right
    End Sub

    Public Property Left As Double
        Get
            Return _Left
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Left = value
            OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyMargin"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Right As Double
        Get
            Return _Right
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Right = value
            OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyMargin"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Up As Double
        Get
            Return _Up
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Up = value
            OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyMargin"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Down As Double
        Get
            Return _Down
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Down = value
            OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyMargin"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property MyMargin As Thickness
        Get
            Return New Thickness(Left, Up, Right, Down)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        If Not PropertyChangedEvent Is Nothing Then
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you just have to add the `XAML`-

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Margin="{Binding Path=MyMargin, FallbackValue=0 0 0 0, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Then on the code behind on the WPF window-

```
Private _NewMargin as New CustomMargin

Public Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()
  MyLabel.DataContext = _NewMargin
End Sub
```

From there you can use whatever control you desire to change all 4 margins separately and the `Class` is reusable for other controls.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it is old, but I was searching for a nicer way:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Margin>
        <Thickness Top="{Binding ElementName=TheMenu, Path=Height}" />
     </TabControl.Margin>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you will get: "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Top' property of  type 'Thickness'."

Comment: It certainly does - there has to be a different cause ... perhaps you can post your code.

Comment: @Paul is correct, you can't set a binding to the Top property of Thickness because it isn't a DependencyProperty, and Thickness isn't a DependencyObject.

Comment: I used it in the past - did something change in the framework?

Comment: @Athanviel I've tried all the way back to .NET Framework 3.0 (the earliest version of .NET to support WPF) and it didn't work even then

Comment: Thanks for checking!
It is a shame the code where I used it, is in my former company - I would love to check. May be there was a plugin that made it work :/
Apparently it worked for some people, that gave those 3 upvotes.