# How to uniquely position usercontrols from an ItemsControl (in MVVM)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to present the usercontrol, CharacterEditorView, from within an ItemsControl. (The use of "Canvas" in the ItemsPanelTemplate can be changed, Grid?). The CharacterEditorView is to overlay on top of a character string, so position is crucial. The ItemsControl is:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CharacterPads}" >
                   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="{Binding Margin}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
```

where the binding of CharacterPads is defined as:

```
   private ObservableCollection<CharacterEditorViewModel> characterPads = new ObservableCollection<CharacterEditorViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<CharacterEditorViewModel> CharacterPads
    {
        get
        {
            return characterPads;
        }
    }
```

I would like to present EACH CharacterEditorView within a specific rectangle known only at the time of its viewmodel creation. That is, each CharacterEditorView will have a different
rectangle to be presented in:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nova5.UI.Views.CharacterEditorView"
       .................................................................
     <Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" Margin="{Binding ...?????}" />
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What binding is needed to position EACH CharacterEditorView at its own position?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: use Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left instead of Margin. Also use Height and Width if you need to define the size of each UI item.

Comment: Similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249518/binding-only-part-of-the-margin-property-of-wpf-control

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Found a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265364/setting-canvas-properties-in-an-itemscontrol-datatemplate

Comment: @AlanWayne for an ultimate example of how to implement this and related features see [My Nodes Editor Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind the TextBlock's `Margin`, you need some bindable property of type [`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within the `CharacterEditorViewModel` and specify this as the binding target (or, for cleaner code, provide numeric properties in the ViewModel and implement a ValueConverter that creates a `Thickness` instance out of them).

Alternatively, since the ItemsPanelTemplate is already defined as `Canvas`, bind those numeric properties directly to `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, as HighCore suggested.