# Binding margin of a grid (or a control) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, binding, margin

I want to bind some controls' margin, let's say, a button for example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MarginConverter x:Key="marginConverter1"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Margin="{Binding MyThickness, 
      Converter={StaticResource marginConverter1}}">
    <Button>Button1</Button>
</Grid>
```

According to the ref. here: [SO: Binding a part of the margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249518/binding-only-part-of-the-margin-property-of-wpf-control/6249638#6249638), I created a `MarginConverter` class and a `MyDataContext` class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (see below), but the `Button1` persists in the top-left position (as if its margin is 0).

```
Public Class MyDataContext
   Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

   Private _myThickness As Thickness = New Thickness(20, 10, 20, 0)

   Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
       Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

   Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
       RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
   End Sub

   Public Property MyThickness As Thickness
       Get
           Return _myThickness 
       End Get
       Set(value As Thickness)
           _myThickness = value
           OnPropertyChanged("MyThickness")
       End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

And the code behind:

```
Dim myDataContext1 As New MyDataContext()
Private Sub Window1_Initialized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized
   myDataContext1.MyThickness = New Thickness(20, 150, 20, 0)
End Sub
```

Please help me to clarify my misunderstanding, even a basic knowledge or a clear explanation from you will be appreciated!

P/S: *My intention for binding the top margin is when user does some specific task, a 25-height border will be appear at the top of the window, so all the existing controls must go down.*
So that if you have another approach, please share here. Thank you.

Comment: i'm not so good at VB, and you didn't supply a `marginConverter1` code, but it looks like you are try to do something on binding, that already a `Thickness` which is more than enough for binding. 
`Margin` have value of `Thickness`, so you need to provide binding with data of type `Thickness` or anything any other type with converter.   PS if you used code from the link AS IS, this wouldn't work, bc they provide a `double` with binding and convert it to `Thickness` with converter, while you already supply a `Thickness`.

Comment: Hi Shakra, thanks for your reply. Yes, I used the VB code of the MarginConverter class in my given SO-link. I will try to figure it out with your suggestion!

Comment: Try your code without `Converter` in Binding

Comment: Dear @Shakra, to have only top margin value, I removed the `MarginConverter` in xaml but the button still stayed there on the top-left. I also tried to add a new property named `MyTopMargin` as `Integer` to use the Converter again, but it didn't work too. I think the issue lies somewhere else... Could you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to provide a height of 25 on top of your grid dynamically,
You can do it by adding a border on top row of the  grid and change its visibility to "Collapsed" to "visible".

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel>
    <Border Height="25"   Visibility="Collapsed">

    </Border>
    <Button >Button1</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Prasanth, you gave me another look at a different angle, but it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here working example for you, sorry but only at C#
app.xaml

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewModel:TestVM x:Key="TestVm"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

ViewModel

```
public class TestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Thickness myThickness = new Thickness(20,10,20,0);

        public Thickness MyThickness
        {
            get { return myThickness; }
            set { myThickness = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Test_Canvas_Chart.Windows.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Test_Canvas_Chart.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{StaticResource TestVm}"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Margin="{Binding MyThickness}">
            <Button>Button1</Button>
        </Grid>

</Window>
```

Window1.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var data = this.DataContext as TestVM;
            data.MyThickness = new Thickness(100,10,20,0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shakra. I find it hard to implement to my existing VB project. But thanks so much for your deep investigation!